# Bootstrap div wrapper

Tags: layout, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to get bootstrap to show something like the attached image, meaning a div wrapper with blue background-color **some padding** and 3 images inside (I use this horrible colors just for the sake of clarity).

[image]

It should be pretty straight forward but, honestly, I couldn't get it. If I try something like :

```
<div class="span9">     
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span9" style="background-color:blue;">
            <img class="span3" src="..."></img>
            <img class="span3" src="..."></img>
            <img class="span3" src="..."></img>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Inside my container class, the tird image does not fit in the wrapper and goes below the other two, as it appears in this image:

[image]

Anyone would give me a hand, please?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to wrap inner `.spanX` in a `div.row`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div class="span9" style="background-color:blue;">     
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <img class="span3" src="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <img class="span3" src="..." />
        </div>
        <div class="span3">
            <img class="span3" src="..." />
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Mmmmm...that is close, but the third image has no right padding with the blue wrapper. I will keep on looking and tell if I find a solution.Thanks

Comment: No way to make it work. Actually (almost) none of the bootsrap based designs I see have this background-colored wrappers, they all have a layout where all items share the page background color. Anyway I am pretty sure there must be a workaround to get it. I will keep looking but I appreciate  any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution is clearing floats? Quite a bit has been written lately on this but here is one article as a start. [Clearing Floats](http://quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html)

From a design and requirements point of view, you might consider something like create divs, then fill them with png images that are extra large then add a transparency to the borders so that have a clear background to appear as if they were bordered as such or show your background color.

The trick I believe for you is to use transparent .png's would do the trick, and or adding the desired look to your images.